# Get 10 posts from a WP_Query. If less than 10, get the remainder from elsewhere

Tags: theme-development, loop

I'm trying to create a related posts WP_Query. So far, I've to created a custom WP_Query that queries all posts that match an array of tags.

However, I'm trying to create a simple `if statement`: if the number of posts fetched are **less than 10**, get the remainder from **elsewhere** (this could be from a particular category).

I have the following loop. It uses `$related_posts->found_posts` to get the number of posts.

```
$related_posts_args =
    array(
    'tag__and' => $list_of_tags, // array of tag IDS
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post__not_in' => $already_posted, // array of post IDs
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
);

$related_posts_query = new WP_Query( $related_posts_args );
if ( $related_posts_query->have_posts() ):
    while ( $related_posts_query->have_posts() ):
        $related_posts_query->the_post();
// this is the number of posts in my current query
    echo $related_posts_query->found_posts; 
            the_title();
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Would anyone know how use the remainder to get posts from elsewhere? (And is possible within the same loop).

Answer (score 8):

You could do something like :

```
$related_posts_query = new WP_Query( $related_posts_args );
if( $related_posts_query->found_posts < 10 ){
   $args = array(/* new wp_query args*/);
   $newquery = new WP_Query( $args );
}

# merge the two results
$related_posts_query->posts = array_merge( $related_posts_query->posts, $newquery->posts );
$related_posts_query->post_count = count( $related_posts_query->posts );

# do your loop here
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach IMO is to count the posts returned per page against the set `posts_per_page` option set in your query. If the count is less than the set `posts_per_page`, calculate the difference and then use this as the amount of posts to fill the rest in a custom query

## This is how it should work:

First, count the amount of posts returned by your "main" query, in this situation, this will be `$related_posts_args->posts`

```
count($related_posts_args->posts)
```

As you have set your `posts_per_page` to `10`, this will be the number to check the count against.

```
count($related_posts_args->posts) < 10
```

If the count is less than 10, you need to get the difference between 10 and the count. This difference will be the `posts_per_page` option for your custom query

```
$ppp = 10 - count($related_posts_args->posts);
```

You can now run your custom query to retrieve the posts to fill the blank spaces. You will just need to add your own query arguments

Here is the complete code

```
if( count($related_posts_args->posts) < 10 ) { 

    $ppp = 10 - count($related_posts_args->posts);

    $args = [ //Add your own query arguments to suite your needs
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'posts_per_page' => $ppp
    ];

    $q = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $q->have_posts() ) {
        while( $q->have_posts() ) {
            $q->the_post();

            //Display your loop elements

        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

With your code integrated

```
$related_posts_args = [
    'tag__and' => $list_of_tags, // array of tag IDS
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post__not_in' => $already_posted, // array of post IDs
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
];

$related_posts_query = new WP_Query( $related_posts_args );
if ( $related_posts_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $related_posts_query->have_posts() ) {
        $related_posts_query->the_post();

        //Display your loop elements

    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

    if( count($related_posts_args->posts) < 10 ) { 

        $ppp = 10 - count($related_posts_args->posts);

        $args = [ //Add your own query arguments to suite your needs
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'posts_per_page' => $ppp
        ];

        $q = new WP_Query( $args );

        if( $q->have_posts() ) {
            while( $q->have_posts() ) {
                $q->the_post();

                //Display your loop elements

            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
    }
}
```